# Windows 10 Controlled folder access, when turned on does it prevent games from saving in documents?

Tags: windows-10, gaming, windows-defender, user-folders, ransomware

Its a feature of windows 10 defender, but it doesn't explain itself well. When turned on, it takes you to a page where there is a list of folders its protecting like Documents and Pictures. They cant be removed. It says "Windows system folders are protected by default". Are those system folders its talking about? If not, why cant i remove them? Documents is needed for game apps to save.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  Yes, by default the `Documents` folder is protected by Controlled Folder Access and those system folders can't be removed, but you can give specific programs (like your game apps) the appropriate access.  When you have some time to spare, read the following for a thorough explanation:  [How to Protect Your Files From Ransomware With Windows Defender’s New “Controlled Folder Access”](https://www.howtogeek.com/329532/how-to-protect-your-files-from-ransomware-with-windows-defenders-controlled-folder-access/).

Comment: And this is another excellent source of information:  [How to Add or Remove Protected Folders for Controlled Folder Access in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87858-add-protected-folders-controlled-folder-access-windows-10-a.html)